# railstutorial.org 4.4.5 exercise 1

Tags: ruby

In the exercise, we have to add a method called "full_name" which takes the first and last name attributes and separates them by a space.

```
class User
    attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :email

    def initialize(attributes = {})
        @first_name  = attributes[:first_name]
        @last_name  = attributes[:last_name]
        @email = attributes[:email]
    end

    def full_name
        "#{@first_name} #{@last_name}"
    end

    def formatted_email
        full_name "<#{@email}>"
    end
end
```

I created 2 separate first and last name attributes, I defined the full_name method, I am stuck on how to implement that method into the "formatted_email" method. I tried

```
"full_name <#{@email}>"
```

but was unsuccessful. Where should I put the full_name?

Comment: What you wrote you tried does not match what you actually wrote in your definition of `formatted_email`.

Comment: The `formatted_email` function reads as *call the `full_name` method with the argument `"<#{email}>"`*.

Answer (score 0):

```
def formatted_email
  "#{full_name} <#{@email}>"
end
```